# Error message when trying to flatten JSON file to CSV

Tags: json, unix, csv, flatten, jq

Trying to flatten a `JSON` file to `CSV` in `UNIX` but getting an error message. Any help here to get the contents copied to `CSV` will be appreciated:

Command:

```
cat Filename.json | jq --raw-output '._data.data[] | [.Date, .Object, .ID, .Name ] | @csv' > /home/Filename.csv
```

Error:

```
jq: error: Cannot iterate over null
```

Comment: What does the json look like?

Comment: edit your question to include the smallest chunk of json that illustrates the problem and your expected output from that input. (Leave your code and error message in place ;-)! ) Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cat Filename.json | sed 1d | sed 's/},/}/' | jq --raw-output '. | [.Date, .Object, .ID, .Name ] | @csv'